# I can’t fit my model using linear_model.fit

Tags: python, scikit-learn, data-science

From `sklearn.model_selection` family I have imported `train_test_split` and I want to train my model and test the model in order to predict variable `y`.

I assigned string data type as my `X` (features/variable of my dataset) and my `y` is an integer dataset (response).

After doing that I have imported `LinearRegression` function/method from `sklearn.linear_model` family, now when I try to fit the model it displays an error

```
can’t convert strings(X) to variable y
```

Why?

```
X = df[['Avg. Area Income', 'Avg. Area House Age', 'Avg. Area 
         Number of Rooms',
        'Avg. Area Number of Bedrooms', 'Area Population', 'Price', 
        'Address']]   
                                
y = df['Price']
```

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split 
 
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size= 0.40 , random_state=101)
```

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

lm = LinearRegression()                                                                                                        
lm.fit(X_train,y_train)
```

Comment: Please add the code that you have so far and maybe an excerpt of your data. It is very hard from this description to really give you a hint.

Comment: Check out the codes

Comment: Also show the complete traceback error. It is always super helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure all the fields (both X and Y) are integer or float (basically they need to be numeric in nature. Linear Regression generates a linear expression of the form y = c1 * x1 + c2 * x2 + c3 * x3 + .... +c0. To apply values to such a formula for calculating predicted value or for generating the formula ALL the fields should be numeric.

Comment: Pls accept the answer if it worked for you :)

Comment: In your example, "Address" looks like a problem. You can do many things : just drop it, reduce it to find the necessary info (ex : City, and then you put an Encoder on it to obtain information from it), calculate a value from it (ex : distance from the adress to a specific place, average salary of the city where the adress takes place, etc). But just don't put the address raw.